# Twitter4j set status to listview

Tags: android, listview, twitter4j

I have a list called `statusses` and among it the text needed which are the tweets called `status`. I want to set the status to `listview`.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView i;
    List<Status> statusess;
    ConfigurationBuilder cb;
    twitter4j.Status status3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        i = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        new LongOperation().execute("");

        }

private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
        Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

        String[] srch = new String[] {"Obama"};
        ResponseList<User> users = null;
        try {
            users = twitter.lookupUsers(srch);
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (User user : users) {
          System.out.println("Friend's Name " + user.getName()); // this print my friends name
              if (user.getStatus() != null) 
              {
              System.out.println("Friend timeline");
              try {
                statusess = twitter.getUserTimeline(user.getName());
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
              for (twitter4j.Status status3 : statusess) 
               {
                      System.out.println(status3.getText());
               }
              }
        }  


            return null;
    }        

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {    

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() { 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }
}
```

now this                           `System.out.println(status3.getText());` works 100%, the tweets are showing in the `console`. but how do I get them to the `listview` in `onPostExecute`?

I tried

```
i.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<twitter4j.Status>(MainActivity.this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, statusess));
```

But I get a lot of text not needed, I need only status3 which is text(tweet), this displays a lot of stuff like tweet id, retweet, followers, etc ..

I also tried this

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {    
    for (twitter4j.Status status3 : statusess) 
    {
    i.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<statusess>(MainActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, status3.getText()));
    }
}
```

but didn't work, a lot of red line xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
users = twitter.lookupUsers(srch);
```

This gives you a list of users. You are running a for-loop to iterate through the list, changing `statuses` on each iteration. When the for-loop ends, `statuses` holds the status list(returned by `twitter.getUserTimeline(user.getName())`) of the *last* user. Is this really what you want?

For example, you can display the user list that is returned using `twitter.lookupUsers(srch)`, in the ListView. And, on a item click event, display the status list for *that* user.

Once you decide on the `user` for whom you need the status list, do the following:

```
// Declare an ArrayList with class scope
ArrayList<String> statusListTextOnly;

// Initialize it in doInBackground()
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    ....
    ....
    statusListTextOnly = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Initialize 'statuses' for the user that you have decided on
    statusess = twitter.getUserTimeline(user.getName());

    // Run a for-loop to fill 'statusListTextOnly'
    // We will use 'statusListTextOnly' with the ArrayAdapter
    for (twitter4j.Status status3 : statusess) {
        statusListTextOnly.add(status3.getText());
    }
}

// Initialize/reset ArrayAdapter
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    i.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, statusListTextOnly));
}
```

The problem with your code lies here:

```
i.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<twitter4j.Status>(MainActivity.this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, statusess));
```

Objects passed to an ArrayAdapter are displayed using the `toString()` method. Now, `toString()` is mostly overriden for custom objects and serves the purpose of providing a meaningful description of the object itself. It can be overriden to provide literally any kind of information in a String format. In case of `Status` objects, `toString()` returns a bit more than what you need. So, we extract the relevant info using `Status#getText()` and store it in a separate ArrayList.

Your second attempt has problems as well:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {    
    for (twitter4j.Status status3 : statusess) {
        i.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<statusess>(MainActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, status3.getText()));
    }
}
```

Here, you are setting the generic parameter of ArrayAdapter to a variable('statuses'): the generic parameter should be a class. Next, you pass a `String` as the last argument, whereas an ArrayAdapter's constructor can either take an array of objects, or an ArrayList. Third, you are creating a new instance of your ArrayAdapter and setting it to the ListView on each iteration of the for-loop. This is logically incorrect. You need one instance of an ArrayAdapter and you only need to set it once.

What else can you do:

- Create a custom ArrayAdapter that affords new functionality, for example: showing of images along with text.
- Dig into BaseAdapter: Highly customizable, all-purpose adapter.

Comment: Thanks! Amazing explanation, codes, and examples.
Accepted, gave, and upvoted =)

Answer (score 2):

```
package com.example.twitterdemo;

import java.util.List;

import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;

public final class GetTimeLines {
    *//**
     * Usage: java twitter4j.examples.GetTimelines ID Password
     * @param args String[]
     *//*
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Twitter unauthenticatedTwitter = new TwitterFactory()
                .getInstance();
        System.out.println("Showing public timeline.");
        try {
            List<Status> statuses = unauthenticatedTwitter
                    .getUserTimeline();
            for (Status status : statuses) {
                System.out.println(status.getUser().getName() + ":"
                        + status.getText());
            }
            if (args.length < 2) {
                System.out
                        .println("You need to specify TwitterID/Password combination to show UserTimelines.");
                System.out
                        .println("Usage: java twitter4j.examples.GetTimelines ID Password");
                System.exit(0);
            }

            // Other methods require authentication
            Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
            statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline();
            System.out.println("------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Showing " + args[0]
                    + "'s friends timeline.");
            for (Status status : statuses) {
                System.out.println(status.getUser().getName() + ":"
                        + status.getText());
            }
            statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline();
            System.out.println("------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Showing " + args[0] + "'s timeline.");
            for (Status status : statuses) {
                System.out.println(status.getUser().getName() + ":"
                        + status.getText());
            }
            Status status = twitter.showStatus(81642112l);
            System.out.println("------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Showing " + status.getUser().getName()
                    + "'s status updated at " + status.getCreatedAt());
            System.out.println(status.getText());
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (TwitterException te) {
            System.out.println("Failed to get timeline: "
                    + te.getMessage());
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```