# Populate ListView with List of Objects

Tags: java, android, listview

I have list if twitter statuses and I want to populate it in a listview

```
public class TwitterTimeline extends Activity {
    List<Status> statuses;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_twitter_timeline);
        setTitle("Timeline");
        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        if (b != null) {
            MyStatuses myStatuses = (MyStatuses) b.getSerializable("statuses");
            statuses = myStatuses.statuses;
            for (Status st : statuses) {// this prints all the status on the  catlog
                Log.d("Abharthan : ", st.getUser().getScreenName()+ ":" + st.getText());

            }

            ArrayAdapter<MyStatuses> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyStatuses>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, statuses);// this line is giving error

            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
```

Here MyStatus Class is:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import twitter4j.Status;

public class MyStatuses implements Serializable {
    List<Status> statuses;
}
```

The layout file containing list view is android_twitter_timeline.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android.HomeWork3.TwitterTimeline">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I populate my listview with twitter statuses using ArrayAdapter or any other method.

Comment: You will definitely need to create a custom Adapter (custom ArrayAdapter or custom BaseAdapter).  The accepted answer here has some good info related to what you're doing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890952/twitter4j-set-status-to-listview

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you will have to create an `ArrayAdapter` with your own data type. Inside, the adapter, you will populate the `view` for each row in the `ListView`.

Then, set that adapter to your `ListView`.

Please check out this guide [Using an ArrayAdapter with ListView](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView). And you will got to use ["Using a Custom ArrayAdapter"](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView#using-a-custom-arrayadapter)

Comment: Here we are using ArrayAdapter and it expects ArrayList as input, but Twitter4j Status is of type List. I tried converting it to Arraylist but it is still not working.                                                                     `public ArrayList<Status> getStatusAsArrayList(List<Status> statuses)
    {
        ArrayList<Status> allStatus = new ArrayList<Status>();
        Iterator<Status> itrTemp = statuses.iterator();
        while(itrTemp.hasNext()){
            Status strTemp = itrTemp.next();
            allStatus = Arrays.asList(strTemp);
        }
        return allStatus;
    }`

Comment: Heh you can convert a `List` to an `ArrayList` with this `new ArrayList<YourType>(myList);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ArrayAdapter or BaseAdapter, here is a example with code, [HERE](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/56268.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Please change the ArrayAdapter from MyStatuses to Status